# Reverse the content of each element in a list python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, reverse

I have a list:

```
lst = ['abcdef', 'uvwxyz']
```

I want to get as result:

```
['fedcba', 'zyxwvu']
```

How can I do that in Python 3 (and Python 2 if it's possible)?

**EDIT :**

Here i want to Reverse **the content of each element** in a list !

**NOT** Reverse **the elements** in the list !

If i do:

```
lst[::-1]
```

I'll get:

```
['uvwxyz', 'abcdef']
```

and that's not what i want !

Comment: Have you done *any* research at all?

Comment: You can index a list or string with a negative step; Python 2 or 3 don't matter here, btw.

Comment: for `python-2.7` i edited my question, and yes i did some research of course, but i just find "Reversing `the elements` in the list", and i want to reverse the `content` of each element.

Comment: @Evert, unless you wish to use `map`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: so look up "*python reverse string*". I bet there's a result or 2 for that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The slice `[::-1]` means to use the entire list/string etc. and step through with a step of `-1`.

so:

```
>>> 'abcdef'[::-1]
'fedcba'
```

Since you need to do this for each item of a list, a list comprehension is a good solution

```
>>> lst = ['abcdef', 'uvwxyz']
>>> [x[::-1] for x in lst]
['fedcba', 'zyxwvu']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=['123','456','789']
l1=[]
for i in l:
    l1.append(int(i[::-1]))
print(l1)
```

Output:`[321, 654, 987]`

Answer (score 0):

```
str1="I am a student from college"
str2=list(str1.split(" "))
print(str2)
reverse=[x[::-1]for x in str2 ]
print(reverse)
```

Comment: That looks like broken syntaxc, but more importantly it looks like no explanation whatsoever. If you add an explanation, I will happily help you with the correct formatting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32476093)